# Simple <script> tag - Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, offline

im trying to create offline desktop application. everything is working fine. The only problem im getting right now its the Origin null is not allowed.

so i have stop doing ajax call. i have simple script include on html via

```
$('body').append('<script id="js-list" src="data/all.js"></script>');
```

after including this line, i still get Origin null is not allowed.

how can i include javascript file or is there anyway else i can include simple json data with keeping it in mind that it is for offline?

Comment: Can you look in the network tab of your Chrome dev tools and look at the requested script URL? If it's using the `file:` protocol instead of `http:` that could be your problem. But it's highly unlikely.

Comment: yes it is using file:// because its offline application. how can go around it? no ajax call, so thats why i went with adding script tag. if this will fail too, is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this instead:

```
list = document.createElement('script');
list.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
list.setAttribute('src', 'data/all.js');
list.setAttribute('id', 'js-list');
```

Comment: This works perfectly with list.onload = function() { trigger on load}; Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
$('body').append('<script id="js-list" src="data/all.js"></' + 'script>');
```

The reason for this is because when the browser sees `</script>` it thinks the js part is finished